# Pass value from one page to another using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I have two pages as Parent.aspx and Child.aspx in my asp.net web application. The values obtained from parent.aspx need to pass to child.aspx code behind page.

The redirect from parent to child happens through javascript. Parent page contains empId which needs to be passed to child page code behind file as the same ID could be used to fetch the details of the employee such as name, age, PIN, bank account details etc.

How to do the same?

thanks!

Comment: can't u pass employee id using query string to  child page? like chilpage.aspx?empid=somevalue

Comment: Waqas,i am using javascript window.open method. In that method i am calling the child page with same syntax like yours.But in child page how can i access empId in .cs page?

Comment: using Request.QueryString["empid"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [ASP.NET QueryString Usage](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring) or any other resources on ASP.NET Query String access. A full example follows.

On the client side:

```
window.open ("http://www.yourwebsite.com?empid=somethin&PIN=somethinglese","mywindow");
```

On the server side (in code behind):

```
string empid;
string PIN;

if(Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
{
    empid = Request.QueryString["empid"];
    PIN = Request.QueryString["PIN"];
}
```

Comment: The child window that i need to open has some fixed size such as height, width etc. Hence i am using js window.open

Comment: So you open the window with the query string parameters and then retrieve them from code behind using the syntax I mentioned above

Comment: Yes i open a window using window.open (search Javascript window.open syntax for more info)

Comment: I added a more specific answer.Does this make the procedure clear?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a session or something similar?

Then in the page load event of ur child page , check that session if not null, then retrieve the data.

Comment: He needs to pass the information from the client side using javascript, he can't use session for that.