# Characters get trimmed when sending values from one page to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am sending some values from one page to another in asp.net using javascript. I have declared JS in parent page and the values are being sent to child page and fetched in code behind page using Request.Querystring. Look to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497069/pass-value-from-one-page-to-another-using-javascript)

To give you a detailed look, See below example

```
chStatusReport.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return Navigate( '" + varTrimmed+ "' );");
```

JS to open a child page is under

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function Navigate(status) {
        window.open("ChildPage.aspx?status=" + status)
        return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Code fetching the value pass from parent to child page.

```
 if (Request.QueryString.Count!=0)

 { svar1= Request.QueryString["status"];
   }
```

Values that are being passed are like 1 )Tom & Peter 2 ) Laurence & Hardy

The values that i get are 1 ) Tom  2) Laurence

Why the remaining text get trimmed?

Comment: I believe there is a specific usage of `&` in a query string, you gotta encode for it and the spaces... URLEncode and URLDecode is what you should look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use & directly in querystring.

You have to either encode or change & to another unicode manually and translate it back.

Here is a link for explanation.

http://www.kamath.com/codelibrary/cl006_url.asp

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually passing `Tom & Peter`?  I.e., `ChildPage.aspx?status=Tom & Peter`?

If you are, then the query string will have:

```
QueryString["Status"] with Tom and QueryString["Peter"].
```

The `&` is a delmiter between value pairs in the query string.

You'll need to URL Encode the URI.  Take a look at [JavaScript encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp).